# OpenVBX not calling

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

I have OpenVBX and just bought a new Twilio number. OpenVBX has been installed with the sid and token of the Active Twilio account. I can send text messages but not receive them. And I can't make any calls or receive them. I tried adding the number to a flow under Admin >> Number >> Numbers used on other Domains: hide. But get an error message.

```
VoiceFallbackUrl is not valid: http://localhost/openVBX/twilio-OpenVBX-5c97301-V2/fallback/voice.php
```

Spec:
    Wamp Server on local computer.
    PHP Version 5.5.29
    cURL support    enabled
    cURL Information    7.42.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ricky from Twilio here.

In order for Twilio to access your website it needs to be available on a publicly accessible URL. We're [pretty big fans of ngrok](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html) as a means of tunneling our localhost to a publicly accessible URL for this purpose. If you spin up ngrok and access OpenVBX through that ngrok URL it should resolve the "VoiceFallbackUrl is not valid" error you're receiving.

Let me know if that helps!